# return a vector from a list based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a list

```
alist <- list(c(1,2,9),c(4,5,4),c(3,11,19))
```

and a constant

```
value <- 4
```

I want to return the vector from the list in which the first element of the vector equals the constant (i.e., (4,5,4)).  I'd like to do this in base R.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `sapply`, extract the first element, compare it with 'value' to get a logical `vector` and subset the 'alist' based on that

```
alist[sapply(alist, `[`, 1) == value]
```

Or with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) x[1] == value, alist)
```

---

If we use `purrr`

```
purrr::keep(alist, ~ .x[1] == value)
```